# Assigning multiple ip's in google cloud platform with cPanel

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, cpanel, google-cloud-platform

This is a google cloud VM,

Setting up cPanel- 
    Multiple external ip addresses

eth0 keeps getting killed when i try adding virtual adapters to eth0 with the external ip's..

```
Jun  3 22:07:02 SERVER1 ntpd[1995]: Deleting interface #3 eth0, 10.128.0.3#123, interface stats: received=50, sent=50, dropped=0, active_time=3690 secs
```

Comment: are you putting it in WHM under Home »IP Functions »Add a New IP Address ?

Comment: Tired there, but can't get all the internal ips setup right on the cloud platform for 1:1 Nat ..

Comment: All that you should have to do is put in local IP and correct subnet mask, and it should take.  You might try posting on the cpanel support site?

Comment: My setup on Google isn't right, because when I did that the rebuild cpnat, can't map the addresses to externals.. only one shows external.. do you know how to get the internal mapped to external using gcloud? One works, but the others I made do not

Comment: I haven't used the gcloud sorry.  I've set up WHM servers on Amazon not Google.

Comment: Is Amazon easy to do 1-to-1 NAT on? The web console in google cloud platform is limited, most operations are done via command line.

Comment: I don't have a point of comparison, but it is pretty straightforward and easy.

Comment: thanks, I'm Usually Well versed with networking in most situations but am not fully experienced with how Google cloud platform does the dirty work.. I shall keep moving forward and will have a solution shortly. Thanks for your help Howard E